# latex label with &

Tags: labels

I need to write a label that contains a '&'.  This is a strange need, but it is for use in a `\keyword` macro, which also adds a string to the aux file, which I can later parse (e.g., with an external program).  Names in English apparently can contain an &, as in S&P~500.

```
\documentclass{article}

\NewDocumentCommand{\keyword}{ m }{%
  \label{KW:\thesection:\thepage:#1}%
  \textbf{#1}
}

\begin{document}

\keyword{abc}
\keyword{def}
\label{i\&j}
\keyword{s\&p500}

\end{document}
```

Error is of course

```
! Missing \endcsname inserted.
<to be read again> 
\&
l.4 \newlabel{i\&j}{{}{1}}
```

How would I ask latex to just consider the & a viable character in a string for the aux file?

advice appreciated.

Comment: `\label{i\string&j}`

Comment: If you insist in using `\&` when producing text: `\makeatletter\newcommand\NotProtectOrProtectModeString{\ifx\protect\relax\expandafter\@firstoftwo\else\expandafter\@secondoftwo\fi}\makeatother` ... `\keyword{s\NotProtectOrProtectModeString{\&}{&}p500}`

Comment: based on ulrich's suggestion: `\makeatletter\newcommand\amp{\ifx\protect\relax\expandafter\@firstoftwo\else\expandafter\@secondoftwo\fi{\&}{&}}\makeatother` and `\keyword{s\amp p500}` should work.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You're abusing `\label` just to write something to the `.aux` file: no such created `\label` can be used in a `\ref`, because you don't know where it will eventually be typeset.

I'd not use `\newlabel` in the `.aux` file, but a different marker.

```
\documentclass{article}

\ExplSyntaxOn
\NewDocumentCommand{\fakelabel}{m}{} % for the .aux file

\NewDocumentCommand{\keyword}{ m }
  {
    \group_begin:
    \cs_set:Npx \& { \token_to_str:N \& }
    \iow_shipout:cx { @auxout }
      {
        \token_to_str:N \fakelabel { KW : \thesection : \thepage : #1 }
      }
    \group_end:
    \textbf{#1}
  }
\ExplSyntaxOff

\begin{document}

\keyword{abc}
\keyword{def}
\keyword{s\&p500}

\end{document}
```

About `\label{i\&j}`, just avoid it or use `\label{i&j}` which works.

The contents of the aux file will be

```
\relax
\fakelabel{KW:0:1:abc}
\fakelabel{KW:0:1:def}
\fakelabel{KW:0:1:s\&p500}
\gdef \@abspage@last{1}
```

Your external program will be able to look for `\fakelabel` and use the supplied data.